# Aggregating a String Field as a Record Indepdent of other Aggregations in GroupBy

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregation

I have data that looks like
`df1`

| Store | owner |
| --- | --- |
| Store1 | A |
| Store1 | B |
| Store2 | B |
| Store2 | C |

and `df2`

| Store | Sold_Item | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Store1 | Apple | 2 |
| Store1 | Orange | 3 |
| Store1 | Apple | 2 |
| Store2 | Apple | 3 |
| Store | Banana | 2 |

I would like to get something like

| Store | Owners | Num_Sales | Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Store1 | A | 3 | 7 |
|  | B |  |  |
| Store2 | B | 2 | 5 |
|  | C |  |  |

I have tried something like:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, how='inner', on='Store')
df_stats = df.groupby(['Store']).agg({"Sold_Item": np.count, "Price": 'sum'})
```

but I cannot what to do with the `Owner` field.

Any advice?

Comment: the Num_Sales and Revenue are for Store and the Owner belongs to the store. The values are only connected to owner via store

Comment: Why do you want this particular output format? Why not just aggregate `Owners` to a list?

Comment: Because I like how it looks stacked on top of one another

Comment: I suggest you look into [stylers](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/style.html)

Comment: Hmm. None of those examples seem to demonstrate what I need. I mean I need to write this to a csv/xlsx file (which I can do without the special structure by, say, joining the `Owners` field in the aggregation. But again, I think it looks really bad to have a comma-separated list in the middle of an excel cell

Comment: In that case @Timeless answer should do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't the last store of `df2` be `"Store2` ?

```
out = (
    df1.merge(df2, on="Store", how="inner")
        .groupby(["Store", "owner"], as_index=False)
        .agg({"Sold_Item": "count", "Price": "sum"})  
)

out.loc[out["Store"].duplicated(), out.columns.difference(["owner"])] = None

# out.to_excel("file.xlsx", index=False) # or `to_csv`
```

Output (*in Excel*) :

| Store | owner | Sold_Item | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Store1 | A | 3 | 7 |
|  | B |  |  |
| Store2 | B | 2 | 5 |
|  | C |  |  |